# Allow contributor to edit own posts after published, without plugin

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to allow contributors to edit (only) their own posts after it has been published. I would like to do this without any plugin and only for a certain custom post type. I cannot seem to find such a code.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, you say that you don't want plugin but you ask for code and the cost must go in a plugin to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. Well i could use a plugin but I would prefer a small clean code. Do you know a plugin that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the capability `edit_published_posts` to your `contributor` role and this will do what you are after.

> edit_published_posts
>   Since 2.0
>   User can edit their published posts. This capability is off by default.
>   The core checks the capability edit_posts, but on demand this check is changed to edit_published_posts.
>   If you don't want a user to be able to edit their published posts, remove this capability. (see also this comment on the Role Manager Plugin Homepage).

And the code to do this is very simple.

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'contributor' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_published_posts

Comment: Yes thanks. Works, but I was wondering if such a thing could also be implemented on CPT level.